# How to store a line in an Array?

Tags: java, arrays, oop

I have been trying to store a ling in a text file in array but I have no been able to do anything about it and I cannot use ArrayList which means it needs to be done manually. This is my code at the moment. By the way, the first line in the text file(the header) should not be included in the array.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main (String[] Args) throws IOException {
        /*Getting the file and going through each line*/
        File planeFile = new File("plane.txt");
        Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(planeFile);

        /*Array to store the flights in*/
        String[] flights = new String[50];

        while(scanFile.hasNext()) {
            for(int i = 0; i < flights.length; i++) {
                flights[i] = scanFile.nextLine();
            }
        Arrays.toString(flights);
        }

    }
}
```

This is the output for my code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.base/java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1651)
        at Main.main(Main.java:20)
```

But I need it to store each line of my text file in an array. This is the file:

```
ID, Destination, Day, Meal, Rows, NumPerRow
9010, Florida, 3, no, 22, 4
9002, Florida, 1, no, 22, 4
9005, Florida, 1, yes, 32, 5
9013, Florida, 3, yes, 32, 5
9008, Florida, 2, yes, 32, 5
9024, Florida, 6, yes, 32, 5
9016, Florida, 4, yes, 32, 5
9021, Florida, 5, yes, 32, 5
9018, Florida, 5, no, 22, 4
9029, Paris, 7, yes, 32, 5
9026, Bahamas, 7, no, 22, 4
9007, Boston, 2, no, 24, 4
9015, Boston, 4, no, 24, 4
9023, Boston, 6, no, 24, 4
9009, NYC, 2, yes, 32, 5
9012, NYC, 3, yes, 32, 5
9004, NYC, 1, yes, 32, 5
9025, NYC, 6, yes, 32, 5
9017, NYC, 4, yes, 32, 5
9020, NYC, 5, yes, 32, 5
9011, Chicago, 3, no, 24, 4
9019, Chicago, 5, no, 24, 4
9003, Chicago, 1, no, 24, 4
9014, DC, 4, no, 22, 4
9006, DC, 2, no, 22, 4
9022, DC, 6, no, 22, 4
9027, Jamaica, 7, no, 24, 4
9028, London, 7, yes, 32, 5
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code will loop for the length of the array, which is hardcoded in this snippet as: 50 slots.

Your file contains fewer than 50 flights, thus, this error occurs.

I'd give advice on how to do such things, but your question goes out of its way to try to impress on us how this boneheaded model of storing this data in a string array is somehow required, so I guess it's.. required.

You said it's required, and your code says that there are 50 flights. Find a way to know beforehand how many flights there are, or arrange for 50 flights to be in the file, or expand on the problem domain to explain what should be done when the file contains fewer than 50 flights (or for that matter, what should happen if there are more than 50 flights).

NB: If your answer is: The array should be exactly as large as there are flight-lines in my text file, then you want ArrayList, not String[]. Note that an ArrayList can rather trivially give you a String[] if you need that someplace else. If this too is not okay, then, well, the java libs are open source. Have a look at how ArrayList works, because you'll be writing a clone of it.

Comment: Thank you for reading my question and helping with the array size. I changed it to 30 slots since there are only 30 lines. However, I still get the same error. I was not trying to impress anyone as I do not have much experience with Java and this is actually my first program in it. ArrayList is not something I can use since my professor told us not to and we have to do it manually.

Answer (score 1):

Are you aware you have 2 nested loops:
The inner for-loop will iterate 50 times (or 30 after your commented change) and read the whole file.
You call hasNext() only once. You must change your code so before each call to `scanner.nextLine()` you have called `scanner.hasNext()`to asure there is one more line.

You have the error because your file has only 29 lines.
If you know the maximum number of lines in the file it's better to rely on the scanner.hasNext() logic:

```
public static void main (String[] Args) throws IOException {
    /*Getting the file and going through each line*/
    File planeFile = new File("plane.txt");
    Scanner scanFile = new Scanner(planeFile);

    /*Array to store the flights in*/
    String[] flights = new String[50];
    int i=0;
    scanner.nextLine(): // skip header line
    while(scanner.hasNext())
    {
        flights[i] = scanFile.nextLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I was aware of the nested loops but I kinda did not notice them for some reason